# Web app https client security: dom/javascript change by user

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, https, web-applications

For a web app using https, user can change DOM and execute javascript from http client such as Chrome devtools. Is there any security concerns?

For example, login using Google account. It uses javascript. Hacker can bypass it by manipulating client DOM and executing javascript using Chrome devtools.

### UPDATE

For sign in with google account:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}
```

Can a Hacker call the sign-in callback directly without going through google auth. can this be a risk? Is there a way to verify the google login on server side?

Comment: Users can change the DOM and run JS on their own browsers, regardless of HTTP or HTTPS. This is why it's important to keep secure things on the server side, and to validate on server side.  The purpose of HTTPS is to prevent Man In the Middle type attacks.

Comment: Understand. For the case of login using google account, after login using google service, all things happens on client side using javascript. From the integration docs, user can modify client code(DOM/JS) to bypass google login.

Comment: A user can only modify their own client / browser -- not someone else's (unless there is some other malicious action like using Man in the Middle).

Comment: Login using google account is done on client side, and not verified on server side, unlike others like reCaptcha. So hacker can login into other user's account by manipulating client DOM/javascript.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I think you need to add details, like step by step description of the scenario you have in mind. I'm not understanding what risk you think there is -- a hacker can't authenticate to Google if they don't have the user's credentials. They can't get another user's credentials by manipulating client side code in their own browser. So what is the security risk?